# Converting sparse tensor dense shape into an integer value in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

If I want to get the shape of a normal tensor in tensorflow, and store the values in a list, I would use the following

```
a_shape=[a.shape[0].value , a.shape[1].value]
```

If I'm not mistaken, using .value converts the element in the tensor to a real number.

With sparse tensors, I type the following

```
a_sparse_shape=[a.dense_shape[0].value, a.dense_shape[1].value]
```

However, I get the error message
" 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value' "

Does anyone have any alternate solutions?

Comment: What's your version of tensorflow? `a.shape` can also run normally with sparse tensors on `version=1.13` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an alternative:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.random_normal([2, 2, 2, 3])
tensor_shape = tensor.get_shape().as_list()
print(tensor_shape)
# [2, 2, 2, 3]
```

Same for sparse tensors:

```
sparse_tensor = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0,0], [1, 1]],
                                values=[1, 2],
                                dense_shape=[2, 2])
sparse_tensor_shape = sparse_tensor.get_shape().as_list()
print(sparse_tensor_shape)
# [2, 2]
```